# How do you configure nginx (dev branch) to refuse to use less than TLS1.1?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I need to configure nginx to require TLS1.1 (and not TLS1.0) at minimum for connections over ssl. I've install the development branch nginx/1.1.16.  How can I configure nginx to require TLS1.1 at a minimum on port 443, and how can I confirm that this configuration is working?

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to make sure you're using a version of OpenSSL that even supports TLS 1.1 (1.0.1 or higher - as yet unreleased, so grab the [beta](http://openssl.org/source/)), and that you're linking nginx against it, otherwise you just can't negotiate 1.1.

Then just set the directive: ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; (the [wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#ssl_protocols) needs updating, but these are the constants I see in the source)